# Combination of function values on subinterval is bounded by $\inf$/$\sup$ of function.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real valued function. And $\mathcal{P} = (x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Why is
$$\inf_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f(x) \leq f(x_{k-1})+\dfrac{f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})}{x_k-x_{k-1}}(x-x_{k-1}) \leq \sup_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f(x)$$ for all $x\in [x_{k-1}, x_k)$ and $k=1,\ldots,n$

Comment: For the second inequality: Is it since plugging in $x=x_{k-1}$ yields $2f(x_{k-1})+f(x_k)$ and letting $x\to x_k$ gives $f(x_k)$ for the middle term and noticing that both terms are $\leq\sup$ and the middle term is linear between the function evaluated at these two endpoints?